# AppTaskWorker - Running class methods at sporadic intervals

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I decided to write a class to do this for me. I had a lot of methods that needed to be invoked at sporadic intervals, across multiple projects.

The dictionary will eventually be class methods, I just put `new Task()...` as an example. I'm fairly new to asynchronous programming, so constructive criticism is 100% welcome.

I set a low interval (10s) on  the main timer because I want to stay as close to the interval in the dictionary as possible. I'm not sure the lowest I can put it without ruining performance.

At some point, I plan to implement non async methods. If anyone has any ideas on how I should implement that, please let me know. I feel like running a non async method inside a task would be a bad idea, maybe a seperate dictionary and process method would work?

Thanks.

```
public class AppTaskWorker : IAppTaskWorker
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Task, DateTime> _tasksLog;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, Task> _tasks;

    public AppTaskWorker()
    {
        _logger = new ConsoleLogger(typeof(AppTaskWorker));
        _tasksLog = new ConcurrentDictionary<Task, DateTime>();
        _tasks = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Task>();

        TryRegisterTask(30, new Task(() => // every 30 seconds
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task 1 has been processed.");
        }));

        TryRegisterTask(120, new Task(() => // every 2 minutes
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task 2 has been processed.");
        }));

        TryRegisterTask(25, new SomeController().Process()); // every 25 seconds

        Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await ProcessActionsAsync();
                await Task.Delay(10000);
            });
        }
    }

    public bool TryRegisterTask(int interval, Task task)
    {
        return _tasks.TryAdd(interval, task);
    }

    private async Task ProcessActionsAsync()
    {
        foreach (var keyValuePair in _tasks)
        {
            var task = keyValuePair.Value;

            if (!_tasksLog.TryGetValue(task, out var lastProcessed))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (!((DateTime.Now - lastProcessed).TotalSeconds >= keyValuePair.Key))
            {
                continue;
            }

            _tasksLog[task] = DateTime.Now;

            try
            {
                await task;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Error(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 2):

`Start()` is spawning an infinite number of new tasks without waiting for them to complete. It's also a bit weird that `Start()` is blocking the calling thread.

Make `Start()` async and await the `Task` returned by `Task.Run`.

`Start()`, a blocking method, being called at the end of the constructor is an absolute no-go. The constructor is not done, the object initialization is never completed.

---

Unless you're living on UTC `(DateTime.Now - lastProcessed).TotalSeconds` is going to be inconsistent around daylight saving transitions.

Comment: I've appended `.Wait` to the task call to wait for it. I wouldn't use `Start()` inside a constructor at production, it gets called outside the constructor now. Thanks for your answer!